# Laravel Many-to-Many relationship Courses and Teachers

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My application (written in Laravel) has **Categories**, **Teachers**, and **Courses** models.

A Course can go into **one** category, and a category can contain multiple courses...

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Course');
    }
}
class Teacher extends Model
{

}
```

My current problem is I need to establish a relationship where a Teacher can have **multiple** courses underneath, and a course can have **multiple** teachers. And this is where I get mixed up.

My current table structure for the databases:

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('course_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            // Teachers? **shrug**
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('teacher_id');
            $table->integer('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: What is your question? What is going wrong with your schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`courses` and `teachers` make a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

So you should define the `many-to-many` relationship in your `Teacher` and `Course` models:

> App\Teacher.php

```php
/**
 * The Teacher has many Courses.
 */
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
}
```

> App\Course.php

```php
/**
 * The Course has many Teachers.
 */
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher');
}
```

This method will look up for a table called `course_teacher`. The `course_teacher` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the `course_id` and `teacher_id` columns.

If you want to override the name of the table just pass it as a parameter in the relationship as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) states.

So now you need to have that table in your database:

```php
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('course_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('teacher_id');
            $table->integer('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// This is the missing table

Schema::create('course_teacher', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('course_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('teacher_id');
        });
```

---

### Side note

I've noticed that you have two columns in your tables that (i'm assuming) might be equal: `id` and `entity_id`, so if you want/need to customize the `Primary key` of the model to match the one of your table, just override it in the model class:

> App\Course.php

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'course_id';
```

You can also configure other parameter like the table name. Read the [Model conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) section of the documentation.

Comment: This is very helpful.

I don't quite get the "Side Note", I assume you mean that `id` and `course_id` are meant to be the same because I don't have an `entity_id` column. I don't actually want them to be the same and would like to avoid using the `course_id` for anything DB-related. This is because the `course_id` column is user-set (like a course ID that a school assigns), whereas `id` is just for the system to use. I have got that worked out though - and thank you for this!

Comment: @G.S. With `entity` i was referring to any model so: `course_id`, `teacher_id` an so on. Yeah I assumed that those values might be equals but now I see the case: ids assigned outside the system. In that case your approach is correct, altough many schools use also a prefix for coding like: 'C-P16' (for a course) or `T-Q28` (for a teacher), so it would be better to store that column as `string`. This is simple an advice of course. Related to the last part, glad your problem is solved.